# How to open a new terminal using _exec function in Windows

Tags: c, windows, security, cmd

My goal is: make an open office macro which downloads an exe file from a distant server and executes it. When the macro executes the file I want a term pop up with an action (ping or other).

This project is to sensibilize from malicious macro files.

So my macro downloader and executer works, but when I want to execute the downloaded exe file Windows detect a virus, block the execution and delete the downloaded exe file.
BUT when I compile in local and execute it, all works.

I know that exe file is not portative but I want to make a demo in my own computer, so the exe file is compiled for my pc, upload to a server and download in my machine.

My theory is: Windows blocks external exe file even if the file is not malicious.

There is the c source file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    _execl("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ping.exe", 
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\ping.exe", 
        "google.com", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: why does Windows block it?
Should I use other function than `_execl()`?

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You describe problems with a program that uses `system()` but you don't show such a program. Instead you show a program that is supposed to run `ping`. Do you have any problems with this program? Please show the program that does not work as expected. Does "*open a new cmd window*" mean that you want to open a new `cmd.exe` window where you can type commands interactively? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: I clarify, is it more clear now ?

Comment: Do I understand right that the question is not how to open a terminal window but how to prevent Windows from blocking your executable program when downloaded from the internet? Windows stores the information that the file was downloaded from the internet in an alternative data stream. Maybe you can remove this stream before trying to execute the program. (A command line tool for this purpose is available from Microsoft / Sysinternals, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) Signing the executable might also help, but this needs considerable effort.